# Visual Studio Team Services with VS 2013-2015 each time I edit file gives me alert: hostname could not be parsed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have a project on Visual Studio Team Services.

I use now Visual Studio 2015 Community, each time I modify a file I got an error on Source Control - Team Foundation console:

```
`Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed`
```

I see my connection from my Team Explorer connection list:

[image: Team explorer Connect]

How can I prevent this error ??

I switch to Server location from Workspace, when I try now to switch back to Local I get an similar error.
If I go to https://jooweb.visualstudio.com I can see my code etc.
If I explore from Source Control Explorer I have no error ....

Where can I find log from error to get more information ?
Is there anything to do to clean TFS cache ... ?

Comment: What is the project your are working on when you get the alert, TFS Project or VSO Project? And can you open the project from IE if it is VSO project?

Comment: Do you put the fully qualified name for the uri?

Comment: @Jerome2606, 1). You don't need to use VPN when work with VSO version controlled projects. 2). What kind of project you're working with? 3). Is the file file you modified contains any URI info? If so, please provide some details on it.

Comment: @Eddie It's a VSO project, and yes I can browse my code from IE

Comment: @TfsAgent I can check-in my changes, all seems to work, just the alert when I save a file or create new file or folder, ... When I check the url I go with "Select Team Projects..." > click on Servers button and there I saw an entry with the TFS project (VSO was ok) when I delete the TFS entry from servers list my error disappear

Comment: Oups talk to fast, error still there :(

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT 1) I know, this is why I shutdown the VPN client 2) Web application 3) No, the error occurs on each files I save (.js, .cshtml, .cs, ...)

Comment: Is there any logs from Source Control Team Foundation where I can have more information on this error?

Comment: Has the file been checked out when you edit and before save it? There is a red mark on the file when it has been checked out.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT No the file do not pass on Check-out status

Comment: Then it is trying to check out the files then you perform save action. Are you using a "Server" workspace? You can check it from "Manage Workspace\Edit\Advanced\Location".

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I use a Local Location, Is there a way to clean all ? I just install VS 2015 Community and experiment same trouble

Comment: @Jerome2606 Does it work if you create a new workspace(Local) for this project?